# Can you solve my meta-problem?

Tags: metapuzzles, bongard

This is a metapuzzle of Bongard problems. Rules (quoted from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41751/what-is-the-answer-to-this-bongard-problem))

> In a Bongard problem, you are given 12 pictures, 6 on one page and 6 on the other. The pictures on the left page conform to a rule, and the pictures on the right page conform to a different rule. Furthermore, a picture on one side cannot conform to the rule on the other side. The goal is to determine the rules.

This is the problem:

[image]

I use the following reference system:

[image]

Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Is the answer simply.. rot13(Gur yrsg fvqr fubhyq or n inyvq Obatneq chmmyr, juvyr gur evtug fnvq vf vainyvq.)?

Comment: @athin yes. it is easy if you already know BPs.

Answer (score 3):

The Bongard problems on the **1** side of the Meta-Bongard are all easy to solve (Numbers are OP's reference system):

**1A**:

> Nothing | Something

**1B**:

> White shape | Black shape

**1C**:

> Square | Non-Square Rectangle

**1D**:

> Big thing | Small thing

**1E**:

> Threesome | Foursome

**1F**:

> Black Circle | White Triangle

The **2** side is significantly harder... (**Bold Numbers** are Meta-Bongard box, *Italic* are Bongard)

**2A**:

> Here, the two sides are exactly the same, so there is no possible rule to differentiate them.

**2B**:

> Here, there is an apparent rule: Arranged | Scrambled.
> Unfortunately, the order of the pieces cannot be used to distinguish the sides of a Bongard problem, and the pieces themselves are otherwise identical.

**2C**:

> This one is the same as **1C** - except that its *2D* has been replaced with a Square, breaking the rule and preventing a new rule from being possible (as the shapes are otherwise identical).

**2D**:

> Here, the two sides are almost, but not quite, identical - shades of **2A**! There is an apparent rule here, though: Bigger | Smaller.
> Unfortunately, much like in **2B**, this sort of comparison isn't a valid way to make a rule, and the "small" things are too close in size to the "big" things to just copy-paste the rule for **1D**.

**2E**:

> Here, both sides are just a single dot, randomly placed. There's *almost* a rule here (Centered | Not Centered), but *2F* breaks it.

**2F**:

> Here, both sides are just noise. I'm sure a dedicated computer could tease a rule out of this one, but it won't be human readable and will feel very contrived - best not to bother.

So what's the rule for the Meta-Bongard?

> I regret to inform you that I cheated - I decoded @athin's rot13 comment under the question. The rule is Valid | Invalid.
> That is, the **1** side are all valid Bongard problems, and the **2** side are all invalid Bongard problems. I had an inkling of this, but **2C** threw me for a loop (I couldn't see that it was different from **1C** until it was too late).

Comment: You may have cheated but the most difficult part was rot13(gb cebir gung gur OC ba gur evtug jrer abg inyvq), so thanks for that detailed answer.